# Laravel 5 Carbon Unexpected data

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, php-carbon

I created new `date` field called `start_date`, and I also have two columns for `created_at` and `updated_at` which are defined as `timestamp`.

In my model I have following line, that should tell Laravel to treat these columns as Carbon objects.

`protected $dates = ['created_at', 'updated_at', 'start_date']`.

In received request, start_date is stored like this:
`2015-10-28T10:37:31.337Z`, and when I try to save it, I got following error:

```
InvalidArgumentException in Carbon.php line 414:
Unexpected data found.
Trailing data

in Carbon.php line 414
at Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', '2015-10-28T10:37:31.337Z') in Model.php line 2925
```

I tried several things, including changing `dateFormat` on Model, changing format on property before saving model, but I keep receiving same error.

What is supposed way to handle situations like this?
Can I have different types of columns handled by Carbon? Do I need to change it change format for them manually? I checked docs, but I couldn't find anything regarding that.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I managed to have that working.

I needed to parse given date before saving

`Carbon::parse($request->input('start_date'));`